# How can I bind collection data as a columns value in a datagrid?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datagridcolumn

I want to bind a collection of data as different columns in a `DataGrid`. The normal way we bind data is bind property. But now my scenario is the properties is a dynamic collection which might be different from different object instances. For each object I need dynamically create a `DataGrid`.

Here I give a simplified live example which is abstracted from my scenario :

```
public class Company
{
    ...
    public string CompanyName { set; get; }
    public ObservableCollection<CompanyProperty> data;
}

public class CompanyProperty
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In my main class, I have a ObservableCollection of Company:

```
class Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Company> _list;
    private void CreateData()
    {
        Company tmp = new Company("Siemens");
        tmp.data.Add(new CompanyProperty() { PropertyName = "Country", Value = "Germany" });
        tmp.data.Add(new CompanyProperty() { PropertyName = "Staffs", Value = "400,000" });
        _list.Add(tmp);


        tmp = new Company("ABB");
        tmp.data.Add(new CompanyProperty() { PropertyName = "Country", Value = "Swiss" });
        tmp.data.Add(new CompanyProperty() { PropertyName = "Staffs", Value = "100,000" });
        _list.Add(tmp);
    }
 }
```

Now I want to bind my data to a `DataGrid` which will be looked like  3 columns(CompanyName, Country, Staffs) and 2 rows(Siemens, ABB).

What I'm struggling with is how to bind the collection of company properties to the different columns in my `DataGrid` since the "Country" and "Staffs" is not properties of "Company" class but only values in an `ObservableCollection` member.

Comment: Can you please [add your solution into an answer and then mark that answer as correct](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so that users know that this question has been answered? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I figured out a solution myself, that is create a DataTable transfer the collection data to the DataTable (we can easily change the values into different columns in the DataTable).

Then instead of bind the "ObservableCollection _list" we bind the DataTable to the datagrid. This seems works.

And I'm still interested to know if someone got some other or better solutions for the kind of senario?